# How do you clear the ApexPages.getMessages() collection in a test?

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagemessages

The longtime frustration of not being able to clear the messages in tests is marked as a delivered idea in Summer '18 here [Add support for clearing PageMessages via Apex](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZLADAA4).

A failing of that forum is that there never seems to be a link to what was actually done, leaving you back in Google land trying to figure out what that was. In this case I haven't found any new methods in the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_apexpages.htm), and can confirm that the second assert here fails using API 45:

```
    System.assert(ApexPages.getMessages().size() > 0);
    ApexPages.getMessages().clear();
    System.assert(ApexPages.getMessages().size() == 0);
```

So how are the messages cleared?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It was easy enough to find the **`Release Note`** for this feature by looking at `Development` > `Apex`.

> ## [Clear Messages on Visualforce Pages While Testing](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_clear_page_messages.htm?edition=&impact=)
>
> Use the new System.Test.clearApexPageMessages() method to clear the messages on a Visualforce page while executing Apex test methods.
>
> Where: This change applies to Lightning Experience and Salesforce Classic in Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer editions.
>
> Why: You can use the System.Test.clearApexPageMessages() method to test the success or failure of each call to controller methods. Using this function along with the ApexPages.hasMessages() and ApexPages.getMessages() methods allows you to test Visualforce controllers more easily.

This method is also included in the documentation on the [`Test Class`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm):

> **clearApexPageMessages()**
>   Clear the messages on a Visualforce page while executing Apex test methods.
>
> **Signature**
>   public static void clearApexPageMessages()
>
> **Return Value**
>   Type: void
>
> **Usage**
>   This method may only be used in tests.
>
> **Example**
>
> ```
> @isTest
> static void clearMessagesTest() {
>     Test.setCurrentPage(new PageReference('/'));
>     ApexPages.addMessage(
>         new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.WARNING, 'Sample Warning')
>     );
>     System.assertEquals(1, ApexPages.getMessages().size());
>     Test.clearApexPageMessages();
>     System.assertEquals(0, ApexPages.getMessages().size());
> }
> ```

Comment: Would be easier still if a link was put back in the idea once the feature was documented in the normal product help. Would have saved 15 wasted minutes of my life and 5 of yours.

Comment: True true. But now anyone who googles it will need only two minutes thanks to the SE network.

Answer (score 6):

OK, with a different set of keywords I hit this [Clear Messages on Visualforce Pages While Testing](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_apex_clear_page_messages.htm) release note that talks about the `Test.clearApexPageMessages()` method. That is explained in the [Test Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_test.htm) documentation.

And happy days, both these assertions pass:

```
    System.assert(ApexPages.getMessages().size() > 0);
    Test.clearApexPageMessages();
    System.assert(ApexPages.getMessages().size() == 0);
```